# Git. How to also move the files uploaded by the user?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, git, capistrano

I have an app that lets users upload PDF documents using Rails Carrierwave. When I deploy using `cap:deploy` the uploads directory on the production server doesn't get included to be moved to the new version. How can I also include it?

Answer (score 4):

Don't move the files. Instead create a symlink to the `shared` directory which persists between deployments.

A typical example is having a `shared/uploads` directory that is symlinked to `public/uploads` after each deployment. Remember to have `public/uploads` set as ignored in your `.gitignore` to avoid conflict when deploying. You could also `rm -rf` the directory before creating the symlink.

The symlink operation looks roughly like this:

```
run "ln -s #{shared_path}/uploads #{release_path}/public/uploads"
```

You could add a separate task for that or just append it to an existing one at the right point.